# What are your job options as a full-time graduate student?

Tags: job-search

I am full-time graduate student not on a work or internship term. What options do I have when it comes to applying for jobs, other than those at my university? Most jobs for students require them to be on an internship or work term, and such jobs tend to be for undergraduate students. I am interested in work relevant to optimization, machine learning, and operations research as I have experience in these areas.

Comment: Does your university have a Career Counselor? Maybe they can give you advise on this.

Comment: *"What options do I have when it comes to applying for jobs, other than those at my university?"* - uhm, you are already graduate (thus have a degree), so you could technically apply anywhere that seeks people with your profile and background

Comment: If you are a full-time graduate student, you may or may not have time for anything else. You need to figure out how many hours you can commit to the job. If it's less than full time, you need to find someone withing reasonable commuting distance who is ok with that. There are usually on-campus resources -- the same guidance folks who set up on-campus recruiting days -- who will have a list of companies that have reached out to the school looking for part-time help. Depending on your field, those may not exist, or may not pay better than on-campus lab assistant.

Comment: _Questions asking for advice on a specific choice, such as what job to take or what skills to learn, are difficult to answer objectively and are rarely useful for anyone else. Instead of asking which decision to make, try asking how to make the decision, or for more specific details about one element of the decision._

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because any detailed answer will be hyper-local to the individual's location, field, availability, interests, and willingness to research what's available.

Comment: And any answer would be dependent on the individual's ability to be both a full time graduate student and an employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am full-time graduate student not on a work or internship term. What
> options do I have when it comes to applying for jobs, other than those
> at my university? Most jobs for students require them to be on an
> internship or work term, and such jobs tend to be for undergraduate
> students. I am interested in work relevant to optimization, machine
> learning, and operations research as I have experience in these areas.

You have to decide if you want a part-time job or a full-time job. Then look for those types of positions. Depending on the employment laws in your jurisdiction the difference between full-time and part-time can impact the types and amount of benefits offered. That can factor into the decision.

Many people find it difficult to be a full-time student and a full-time worker, but others are able to handle it.

Start with either your university department or the general career assistance office at your university. They may have leads or contacts that are relevant to your education and experience. They may also have leads for generic jobs not tied directly to your area of study.  You can also talk to your professors.

Because you have a degree you may find that you qualify for many full-time jobs. Your situation isn't much different from somebody who gets their first degree, finds a full-time job, then picks a local university for their graduate degree. You are just doing the steps in a different order.